# Large number of constants in an enum

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I have a list of available coordinate reference systems which I want to represent as an enum, like so:

```
import enum


class CRS(enum.Enum):
    WGS84 = '4326'
    POP_WEB = '3857'
    UTM_33N = '3767'
    # etc. etc.
```

This worked just fine when we supported just a few coordinate systems, but now as we've decided to support some 60 additional ones, the list will grow large.

Is there an alternative to typing the list by hand?

Comment: If you have constants with specific values, i dont think you can avoid typing/copying/reading from file them at least once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can read the key/values from a CSV file or whatever, store them as a dict and initialize the enum as follows:

```
>>> d = {"WGS84" : "4326", "POP_WEB" : "3857", "UTM_33N" : "3767" }
>>> e = enum.Enum("CRS", d.items())
```

Now you can access the enum values as usual:

```
>>> e.POP_WEB
<CRS.POP_WEB: '3857'>
>>> e.WGS84
<CRS.WGS84: '4326'>
```